The sum of the first $n$ prime numbers divided by the $(n+1)$th prime number
It is known that the asymptotic behavior of the $n$th prime number is given by $$p_n\approx n\log n$$ and $$p_1+p_2+\ldots +p_n\approx {1\over 2}n^2\log n$$ These results are advanced. They imply $$ {p_1+p_2+\ldots +p_n\over p_{n+1}}\to \infty \quad (1)$$
Is there a more elementary proof of $\bf (1)$ ?
For example the condition ${p_n\over n^2}\to 0$ would be sufficient as $p_1+\ldots +p_n\ge \sum_{k=1}^nk\approx {n^2\over 2}.$
The property $(1)$ has been applied in  this answer.
I was trying to use the Euler theorem $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over p_n}=\infty\quad (2)$$ in vain. The proof of property $(2)$ is not extremely hard. It makes use of basic facts concerning the infinite products.

You have to edit "property $(2)$" (a famous Euler's result) .

@Piquito OK. Done.

$(2)$ still is not an equation.

@DietrichBurde Thanks, corrected.

Yes, $(2)$ is elementary. But your result is more difficult, I think.

Dusart proved $1998$ the bound
$$
p_1+\cdots +p_n > \frac{1}{2}n^2(\log(n)+\log(\log(n))-2),
$$
and $1999$ the bound
$$
p_n<n(\log(n)+\log(\log(n))
$$
for all $n\ge 6$. Applying this for $p_{n+1}$ and for its reciprocal, this yields
$$
\frac{p_1+\cdots +p_n}{p_{n+1}}>\frac{n^2}{4(n+1),}
$$
which tends to infinity for $n\to \infty$. Dusart's proof is fairly elementary, but there might be still  an easier bound.
Reference:
Asymptotic expression for sum of first n prime numbers?

Starting form the Prime number Theorem (which has an elementary proof due to Erdos and Selberg), an elementary derivation of an asymptotic formula for the sum of the first $n$ primes can be found in Theorem 2.3 of this paper. This result proves that

Alternatively, since $p_n \sim n\log n < n^{1+\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, as $n \to \infty$ it implies the proportion of numbers formed by the sequence of ratios $\frac{p_1}{p_n},\frac{p_2}{p_n} \ldots, \frac{p_{n}}{p_n}$ which fall inside any sub-interval within $(0,1)$ is proportion to the length of that interval i.e. the sequence $\frac{p_r}{p_n}$ approaches equidistribution in $(0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence we have

Theorem: Let $p_k$ be the $k$-th prime and let $f$ be a continuous function Riemann
integrable in $(0,1)$ then,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}f\Big(\frac{p_r}{p_n}\Big) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx. $$

(See the proof of the theorem in this MO link). Taking $f(x) = x$, we get
$$
p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_n \approx \frac{n p_n}{2} \approx \frac{n^2 \log n}{2} \approx \frac{n p_{n+1}}{2}
$$
since by the Prime number Theorem, $\displaystyle \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} \to 1$.

Thanks for the answer!  The accepted answer refers to your work, showing more elementary proof than the  classical ones. I have noticed that you have joint paper with theoretical physicist Marek Wolf, whom I know as he worked several years at Wrocław University.
